# Servlet 3.0 Spring Java Config JNDI

Tags: java, spring, config, servlet-3.0

I am trying to replicate the `resource-ref` attribute of `web.xml` in my spring web apps  `WebApplicationInitializer` to configure JNDI.

How would I do this:

```
<resource-ref>
<description>Connection Pool</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/LocalCheddar</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.Datasource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

in java config rather than xml?

Answer (score 12):

Looking into the spec for servlet 3.0 I found the `@Resource` annotation. Instead of in my `WebApplicationInitializer` class it's now in my `WebConfig` class.

```
@Bean
@Resource(name="jdbc/MyDB")
public DataSource dataSourceLookup() {
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDB");
    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: I could't get this to work. What exactly do you mean by "WebConfig"? The class extending the WebMvcConfigurationSupport?

Comment: WebConfig - java configuration (extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter)